# Only printing in console lines containing 'the' in text file: Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Help!!
I have been set this task but i'm really unsure how to do this:

```
    Sub Main()

    Dim filePath As String = "C:\...\Projects\testing.txt"
    Dim fileHolder As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim line As String

    fileHolder = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(filePath)
    line = fileHolder.ReadLine()

    While line <> Nothing
        Console.WriteLine(line)
        Console.WriteLine("*****")
        line = fileHolder.ReadLine()
    End While
    Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub
```

"Edit the above program so that it only writes lines beginning with “The” to the console. You may find it helpful to revisit the lesson on String Handling to complete this task."

I have tried using if statements inside the while loop or a Do Until loop inside the While one, however this meant it would print the first line that contained "the" and not the third line that also contained "the", as the second line didn't.
Here is the (really bad code) that has failed me so far:

```
    Dim filePath As String = "C:\...\Projects\testing.txt"
    Dim fileHolder As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim line As String

    fileHolder = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(filePath)
    line = fileHolder.ReadLine()
    Dim the As String = "the"

    While line <> Nothing
        If line.ToUpper.Contains(the.ToUpper) Then
            Console.WriteLine(line)
            Console.WriteLine("*****")
            line = fileHolder.ReadLine()
        End If
    End While
    Console.ReadKey()
```

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: You should add what you have tried so far (code), and what exactly didn't work about it.

Comment: Move `line = fileHolder.ReadLine()` below `End If`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim filePath As String = "C:\...\Projects\testing.txt"
Dim fileHolder As System.IO.StreamReader
Dim line As String

fileHolder = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(filePath)
line = fileHolder.ReadLine()
Dim the As String = "the"

While line <> Nothing
    If line.ToUpper.Contains(the.ToUpper) Then
        Console.WriteLine(line)
        Console.WriteLine("*****")
    End If

    line = fileHolder.ReadLine()
End While
Console.ReadKey()
```